# pthread_create() appears to leak memory

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I've written a simple `wrapper.so` over `calloc()` and `free()` to monitor memory calls and appears that `pthreads_create()` is leaking memory.

After an initial allocation with `calloc(17, 16)` (most of the time `calloc(18, 16)`), it seems like that memory is being attempted to be free'd, but a `nullptr` is passed to `free()` instead.

What's happening here?

```cpp
// test.cpp

#include <pthread.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

void* p_dummy(void*)
{
    return nullptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    void* ptr = calloc(11, 11);
    free(ptr);

    pthread_t thread;
    assert(pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, p_dummy, nullptr) == 0); 
    assert(pthread_join(thread, nullptr) == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// wrapper.cpp

#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cstdio>

static void  (*real_free)(void* ptr)                   = NULL;
static void* (*real_calloc)(size_t nmemb, size_t size) = NULL;

static bool initializing = false;

static void init()
{
    initializing = true;

    fprintf(stderr,"init()\n");

    real_free = (void (*)(void*))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");
    real_calloc = (void* (*)(size_t, size_t))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "calloc");

    if (!real_free or !real_calloc) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in `dlsym()`: %s\n", dlerror());
    }

    initializing = false;
}

extern "C" void free(void *ptr)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"free(%p)\n", ptr);

    if (!real_free) {
        init();
    }

    real_free(ptr);
}

extern "C" void* calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    static char memory[32] { 0 }; // Hack to provide memory to dlsym()

    if (initializing) {
        fprintf(stderr,"calloc(%lu, %lu): %p\n", nmemb, size, &memory);
        return memory;
    }

    if (!real_calloc) {
        init();
    }

    void* ptr = real_calloc(nmemb, size);

    fprintf(stderr,"calloc(%lu, %lu): %p\n", nmemb, size, ptr);

    return ptr;
}
```

```
# Makefile

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -Wall

all: test

test: test.cpp wrapper.so 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -pthread -o test test.cpp -ldl

wrapper.o: wrapper.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -fPIC -o wrapper.o wrapper.cpp

wrapper.so: wrapper.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o wrapper.so wrapper.o -ldl

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so test
```

Output:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./wrapper.so ./test
init()
calloc(1, 32): 0x7f2a02bf1080  -- dlsym() requests memory
calloc(11, 11): 0x7fffd400d260 -- calloc(11, 11) in test.cpp
free(0x7fffd400d260)           -- free() in test.cpp
calloc(17, 16): 0x7fffd400d2f0 -- pthread_create() requests memory
free((nil))                    -- an attempt to free previously allocated memory?
```

Comment: Threads have [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed memory for their [call stack](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). See [clone(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) and study the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). It is free software. Also `fprintf` will call `malloc`

Comment: `fprintf`, and friends, are relatively high level library functions that may employ malloc/free themselves. Calling them from hijacked malloc/free calls might produce unstable results.

Comment: There are at least two different things the people may mean by "memory leak".  One is that a program does not free all memory it allocated before it exits.  Your program appears to exhibit such behavior, but this kind of leak is is not of much consequence if that's all there is to it.  The memory leak you need to worry about is when a program allocates memory and then loses the pointer to it, so that it *cannot* free that memory.  And even this is only a significant problem leaks that are individually large or may become large in the aggregate.

Comment: To be clear, I am not advocating sloppy programming.  I'm just saying that the behavior demonstrated in the question, if indeed the output accurately reflects the program's behavior, is not enough to give me reason for concern.

Comment: Trigger a breakpoint at that `nil` and see stacktrace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory region in question is the DTV (dynamic thread vector), which can't be deallocated until program termination.

You can see it in GDB if you break on `calloc`:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __libc_calloc (n=17, elem_size=16) at malloc.c:3366
#1  0x00007ffff7fc52fa in calloc (nmemb=17, size=16) at wrapper.cpp:56
#2  0x00007ffff7fe39cb in allocate_dtv (result=0x7ffff7d86700) at ../elf/dl-tls.c:286
#3  __GI__dl_allocate_tls (mem=mem@entry=0x7ffff7d86700) at ../elf/dl-tls.c:532
#4  0x00007ffff7f8b323 in allocate_stack (stack=<synthetic pointer>, pdp=<synthetic pointer>, attr=0x7fffffffe300) at allocatestack.c:622
#5  __pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=<optimized out>, attr=<optimized out>, start_routine=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:660
#6  0x0000555555555273 in main () at test.cpp:19
```

That's by design (more details [here](https://chao-tic.github.io/blog/2018/12/25/tls) if you're really curious).

Many bugs were reported about the "leak" in `allocate_dtv`, all of which were rejected (example [1](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3087), [2](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4410)).

The call to `free(nullptr)` is unrelated to this, it's called from a thread cleanup function (`__res_thread_freeres`).

Answer (score 3):

I added:

```
extern "C" void free(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        raise(SIGTRAP);
    }

     ....
```

then fired up a debugger:

```
gdb --args env LD_PRELOAD=./wrapper.so ./test
```

`run` it and `bt` showed:

```
free((nil))

Thread 2 "test" received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7a25640 (LWP 418295)]
0x00007ffff7c0a702 in raise () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7c0a702 in raise () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7fc1252 in free (ptr=0x0) at wrapper.cpp:39
#2  0x00007ffff7ab8027 in __libc_thread_freeres () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7c0027f in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff7b275e3 in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

A trivial google search resulted in [__libc_thread_freeres](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/thread-freeres.c.html#30) which calls [__strerror_thread_freeres](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strerror_l.c.html#60) which calls `free(last_value)`. The `last_value` is used as a thread-local value for memory allocated by `strerror_l`. And it's `NULL`, `strerror` was never called.